# force.com sites - direct link to salesforce visual force page not working

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

Am facing an obstacle using force.com site
a template email is used to send to portal users with direct link to some record in salesforce
example `https://example.force.com/SamplePage?id=xxxxx`

by trying to use refURL param half way was done as in  the next example :

```
https://example.force.com?refURL=/SamplePage?id=xxxxx
```

but passing from an obstacle to facing another,now every time i click on the  new link in the email i have to re-login again regardless that i just made a login.

so for the first attempt its logical to input the credentials to login to the site but i need to prevent when the session still on to re login again every time by clicking on the link from my email
my login code in Apex is as below :

```
global PageReference login() {

    //Get refUrl
    String strRefUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('refURL'); 

    //Get startUrl
    String strStartUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL'); 

   if(strRefUrl != null && strRefUrl != '' && ! strRefUrl.startsWithIgnoreCase(Site.getBaseInsecureUrl() )){     
        //Need to remove domain part because site.login() does not redirect to absolute URL
        strStartUrl  = strRefUrl.replace(Site.getBaseRequestUrl(),'');
    }
    else if (strRefUrl.startsWithIgnoreCase(Site.getBaseInsecureUrl())){ 
        //Redirect to base URL if refUrl is empty
        strStartUrl = Site.getBaseUrl() + '/LoginPage';
    } 

    return Site.login(username, password, strStartUrl );

}
```

Comment: Can you debug and check value of `strStartUrl`

Comment: am facing no issue with login , logging in pass fine and i do have redirection to desired page here is `SamplePage` but what am asking is what  i have to do to prevent logging in every time i click on the direct link when a session is still open